# What is the Java equivalent of NuGet?

Tags: java, nuget

I'm just embarking on some Java work after working exclusively in C# for about a decade; I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE. I can't find the equivalent of NuGet for Java. How do Java developers re-use third party code? NuGet solves so many problems for me in .NET that I can't believe there isn't a direct equivalent...?

Comment: [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)?

Comment: Investigating Maven. First problem: I can create a Maven project, or an Android project, but not both :( Installed Maven and discovered I need an Android plugin. Downloaded the samples provided with the android plugin, they fail to compile. I am losing the will to live.

Comment: nice q, suggestion you add C# tag?

Answer (score 36):

After several hours of following dead ends, installing Maven, customizing environment variables and chasing down dependencies, I eventually found that in IntelliJ under `project structure` it is possible to add a library directly from Maven. Perfect!

Comment: Intellij does have extensive support for maven. Dependencies are automatically added to your project as you declare them in the Pom.xml. All you have to do is enable maven support for your project. Simply right-click your project and choose "Add framework support" and choose maven. Then you will see the maven tool window added to your editor window.

Answer (score 4):

In java world for dependency management java we can maven (Commonly used) or ivy (little used) , Gradle (Latest) .

To get install third party jar in any ide use **maven update**

If you use maven you will be **pom.xml** where you will be mention about dependency .